# How many strict local maxima the function $|p(x)|$ might have for any cubic polynomial $p:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, roots, maxima-minima

Instead of looking for roots of a polynomial $p:\Bbb R^n$, we might be interested about the points at which $p$ is "furthest" from having a root:

> **Question.** What is the maximum number $N$ of strict local maxima of the function $|p(x)|$, where $p:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is a cubic polynomial?

---

The answer in case of a quadratic polynomial $p$ was trivial: [At how many isolated points in $\Bbb R^n$ might the distance of a quadratic polynomial $p:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ from 0 be locally maximized?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4620675/1134951) However, it seems to me that in case of a cubic polynomial we run into the same problems as those that I describe in the question: [How many strict local minima a quartic polynomial in two variables might have?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620663/how-many-isolated-local-minima-might-a-quartic-polynomial-in-two-variables-have)

---

As @GerryMyerson commented, $N\leq 2^n$ because by Bézout's theorem the partial derivatives of $p$ can be zero simultaneously at no more than $2^n$ points. Can this upper bound be attained?

Comment: I left a comment at the other question. By the same reasoning involving partial derivatives and Bezout's Theorem, I'd expect the cubics to have $2^n$ isolated local extreme points.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks a lot for this idea. This gives us the upper bound $2^n$. I guess it should not be hard to choose the polynomial $p$ so that its partial derivatives wont vanish at the same point at infinity. What might potentially be challenging is making sure any of the critical points of $p$ were saddle points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Proposition.** $N = 2$.

**Proof.** As argued in [A cubic polynomial in $n$ variables has at most one strict local minimum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4620638/1134951), a cubic polynomial has at most one strict local minimum. Applying this to $p$ and $-p$, we conclude that $|p|$ has at most two strict local maxima (one corresponding to a local minimum of $p$ and the other to local maximum of $p$). Clearly this limit is attained, for example by the polynomial
$$
  p(x,y) = x(x^2-3) + y (y^2-3),
$$
which has a strict local maximum at the point $(-1,-1)$, a strict local minimum at the point $(1,1)$, and the two remaining critical points $(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$ are saddle points. $\tag*{$\Box$}$