# How to find a cubic polynomial in two real variables with four saddle points?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, roots, maxima-minima

> What would be a systematic way to find a cubic polynomial $p(x,y)$ with 4 saddle points?

A cubic polynomial can have at most 4 critical points. Note that no more than 2 critical points can lie on a line (since $c$ along a line is a cubic polynomial in one variable and thus can have at most two critical points). Therefore, any cubic polynomial with 4 critical point can be modified by an affine transformation so that it has critical points $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)$. Normalizing $c(0,0)=0$ in addition to it, we get the following formula for all polynomials with the mentioned properties:
$$
p(x, y) = a\left(x^3 - \frac{3}{2}x^2\right) + b\left(y^3 - \frac{3}{2}y^2\right) + c\left(x^2y + xy^2 - xy\right).
$$
What remains is to choose $a,b,c\in \mathbb R$ so that:

1. The determinant of the Hessian at the three mentioned points is negative.
2. The polynomial has a 4th critical point $(u,v)$.
3. The determinant of the Hessian is negative at $(u,v)$.

At this point one could use some "frute-force" approach, like to randomly keep generating $a,b,c$ until all three conditions were satisfied, however I would be interested in a more systematic method:

> How to find an example of $(a,b,c)\in \Bbb R^3$ satisfying the nonlinear inequalities implied by conditions 1.-3. using a freely available program?

---

Related:

- [Can a cubic polynomial in two real variables have three saddle points?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446848/497175)
- [Can a cubic polynomial in two real variables have exactly three isolated critical points?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699840/can-a-cubic-polynomial-in-two-real-variables-have-exactly-three-isolated-critica)

Comment: Are you sure that there is a cubic polynomial $f(x, y)$ with four saddle points? Do you find any example by your brute-force approach?

Comment: I later realised that there are no four saddle points. However, i would still be interested what wold the mmm

Comment: OK. There is no such a cubic.